# How can we deal with layers in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, components, tailwind-css

This is a landing page
[Landing Page Website Raact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RxMg.png).

When I scroll down my slider came on front of navbar which is displayed in the bottom image
[Error in this Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIVyR.png). So please help me to out to put slider in the back of navbar.

I want the slider to be below the navbar on scroll on on the above of it. I have kept the navbar fixed.

Comment: Please include your HTML/CSS in your question - screenshots are helpful, but it can be difficult to determine the exact problem just from a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `position: fixed` with an HTML structure something like this...

```
<body>
 <header style="position: fixed"/>
 <main> 
   <!-- rest of your scrollable content> 
 </main>
</body>
```

You can just swap the order of your header and main elements:

```
<body>
 <main> 
   <!-- rest of your scrollable content> 
 </main>
 <header style="position: fixed"/>
</body>
```

Since the `<header>` is now later in the DOM structure, it will inherently have a higher z-index, and so will appear on top of the `<main>` content.  And since you are using `position: fixed`, the location of the element on the page won't really change.

Answer (score 0):

Give a higher z-index for your header than the slider in your CSS file.
e.g. `z-index: 999;`